How to LOCK with READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT
I could not figure out how to explicitly lock a table from reading in READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT mode?
Based on my knowledge:
when READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is OFF
BEGIN TRAN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

-- Locks the table from reading (Fine)
select LastOrderNumber from IncrementalNumbers WITH (TABLOCKX);

-- Do other stuff in backend

-- Locks the table from reading (Fine)
update Orders set Reference = 'ORD-001';
-- Table is already locked, so no worry
update IncrementalNumbers set LastOrderNumber = 1;

COMMIT

when READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is ON
BEGIN TRAN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

-- Does not lock the table from reading (even if WITH (TABLOCKX) specified) (Wrong)
select LastOrderNumber from IncrementalNumbers WITH (TABLOCKX);

-- Do other stuff in backend

-- Does not lock the table from reading (Fine)
update Orders set Reference = 'ORD-001';
-- Should be locked in the select above, but it's not
update IncrementalNumbers set LastOrderNumber = 1;

COMMIT

The question is how to use READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT mode and at the same time in some situations be able to lock the table from reading? Eg. to avoid incremental numbers (eg. [Reference]) being read and then overridden. Is it possible?

The question is unclear. Why would incremental numbers generated by eg IDENTITY or SEQUENCE get overwritten?  'ORD-001'; is neither a number nor incremental. Whatever the real problem is, it probably doesn't require locking. Explain what you're trying to do, why IncrementalNumbers is used at all instead of using eg a SEQUENCE

@PanagiotisKanavos I have updated the question to better explain my use case.

Not really, you repeated what's already written. Why do you even use IncrementalNumbers instead of SEQUENCE ? How is LastOrderNumber generated? Even if you can't use SEQUENCE for some reason (why?) you could use UPDATE with an OUTPUT clause to both increment a column and return the new number

@PanagiotisKanavos what you asking is outside of the question. But I can answer. IncrementalNumbers is one single row table. LastOrderNumber is incremented by update and some times reset back to 0 (annually).  Reference is being set only if the order published. There is no ref when it's in Draft. -- Do some work in backend there are more stuff involved in the backend (like preparing templates and calculating costs) on publish and on failure is being rolled back as a whole transaction.

Are you sure it's not relevant? Overcomplicated techniques usually hide other problems and cause trouble. Everything you want is already handled by SEQUENCE except rolling back BUT in real businesses orders don't get rolled back. Rolling back may not be a real requirement, just how you thought the solution would look like to the real problem. In real businesses orders may get cancelled, refunded, modified but they don't just disappear. You don't even have an order until the point you call "publish". You have may have a cart or whatever.

If the order number is generated at the last moment before the pre-order becomes an order, it won't have to be rolled back for business reasons. If something goes wrong, eg the database crashes, you'd want to recover the order and complete it, even manually, instead of discarding it. That means you do want that order number kept, as long as there was no business error. That's done by actually recording the order number a little before publishing. Even if that order numbers is sent to the tax authorities, there are procedures to reverse or compensate mistakes. That's basic accounting.

@PanagiotisKanavos a rollback is performed if any exception happen. It could be a system exception like "division by zero" or user exception like "tax regime not selected". I don't see any issues here.

Something that should happen in application code, not the code that saves data. You can't rollback business processes, especially when they involve third parties, anyway. In some countries the receipt number is generated by an external device or (nowadays) government web service. I don't see any issues and yet, you can't get the database to work the way you expected.

And I suspect SNAPSHOT is used to avoid blocks by inefficient data access code. Perhaps code that tries to perform multiple processes in a single stored procedure.

ALTER TABLE in a transaction will acquire an exclusive schema lock, preventing all readers and writers.
Although that’s overkill to “avoid incremental numbers (eg. [Reference]) being overridden”.  For that the writers can lock each other out by reading with an UPDLOCK hint in a transaction.

For that the writers can lock each other out with an UPDLOCK hint.
It's too late for that. I need them to be locked on select. So any other thread which do the same op will wait.

The op should SELECT with UPDLOCK in a transaction so they block each other.

Ok, I got your answer. It does not lock from reading. But it does from locking. Got ya. So the second example is correct as soon as others would need to always try to lock the [IncrementalNumbers] table on reading. Thanks.

What's wrong with READCOMMITEDLOCK, UPDLOCK

Using both is redundant, as you’ll just get U with or without READCOMMITTEDLOCK. That will just us S locks instead of row versioning for reads.

But using UPDLOCK on the read side will force a U-lock instead of a S-lock, and will hold it to the end of the transaction.

But an S lock is not enough, as multiple writers can acquire an S lock, then create inconsistencies, or cause deadlocks.  Pure readers can continue to use snapshot reads.  In RCSI you need U and X locks, but opting in to using S locks is not very useful.

When READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is ON then READ COMMITTED mode by default becomes row-versioned, and therefore does not block if there are locks on the table.
To force standard mode, you need to use READCOMMITTEDLOCK hint. You also need a UPDLOCK to prevent it ignoring S-locks. You need to do this on the reader side. See the docs.

When the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option is ON, you can use the READCOMMITTEDLOCK table hint to request shared locking instead of row versioning for individual statements in transactions running at the READ COMMITTED isolation level.

You can also use a SERIALIZABLE hint instead to promote to the serializable level, which would probably be prudent in your particular case.
Why you'd want to lock the whole table is another question. It sounds like you should actually be using a SEQUENCE object instead.

In my that particular case there is only one record in the table, but yes I agree, it would be better to lock the only what's being read for modification.

Thanks to David Browne - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78653068/1143349 tip, I realized what the answer is.
It does not lock [IncrementalNumbers] from reading. But it does from locking.
So the second example is correct as soon as others would need to always try to lock the [IncrementalNumbers] table on reading.
So everyone who wants to read the LastOrderNumber for modification (not just for display purpose) would need to always read with lock:
select LastOrderNumber from IncrementalNumbers WITH (TABLOCKX);


